# Asp.net Core: middleware to controller conversion issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Swagger project where I'm doing OAuth (token provider + verification). Everything is working fine, but the token provider was implemented as middleware based on a sample I found online. I want to convert the token provider middleware to a controller so it shows up in Swagger and users quit bugging me on how to get a token :).

In the startup.cs, I created a TokenProviderOptions object and populated it with values that live in the startup.cs (since they also get passed to the oauth verification part). I was then doing:

```
app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(tokenProviderOptions));
```

and the middleware was getting the options.

Now that I'm getting rid of the middleware, how can I pass in the tokenProvider options to the controller? Seems kind of weird to put it in DI as a singleton.

Comment: I'm curious, did you use the DarksideCookie blog to do your OAuth originally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve options from the dependency injection container in controllers and other services using the `IOptions<T>` interface. For example:

```
public class TokenProviderController
{
    private readonly IOptions<TokenProviderOptions> _options;

    public TokenProviderController(IOptions<TokenProviderOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }
}
```

You can then access the options values using `_options.Value`.

The options can be configured in the startup class. Typically you populate them from configuration:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<TokenProviderOptions>(Configuration);
    }

    // ...
}
```

If your options consist of hard-coded values, you can use a delegate to configure the binding:

```
services.Configure<TokenProviderOptions>(o =>
{
    o.Foo = "Bar";
});
```

For more info check out [the documentation on the options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options).

Comment: I got it to work by passing in (null, (x) => set options)... was that your intention? In your code sample, where would you pass in the TokenProviderOptions instance?

Comment: @SledgeHammer there are different ways to configure the options. If your configuration consists of hard-coded values you can indeed use a delegate to bind them. Please take a look at the updated answer and the documentation I linked to.